# How to remove bloom/glow in Prey 2017 (CryEngine 4)?

Tags: prey

how I can remove bloom/glow? I tried tweaking the config files (*game.cfg*, *system.cfg*, *autoexec.cfg*); any idea how to remove bloom/glow with commands in the *autoexec.cfg* file or another way? I already tried any related command preset in the [official documentation](https://docs.cryengine.com/display/CRYAUTOGEN/CONSOLEPREFIXR) (CryEngine 4).

I also try to enable the in-game console but not work... some suggest to use the [CryEngine Remote Console](https://community.pcgamingwiki.com/files/file/908-cryengine-remote-console/), but I have not been able to make it work.

[image: the bad eccessive glow around the pistol]

**Game version:** Epic Store

Comment: Hi, welcome to Arqade! Why doesn't editing the .cfg files work? I mean, you tried it, so I assume nothing happened? Can you set the file to 'Read-only' after editing and see if that works?

Comment: @Joachim I already tryed any related command (really, any of them: r_Glow r_HDR... etcetera) in all .cfg files simultaneously (all .cfg files in saved games folder and in game folders), and .cfg files setted to read only... not work.

Comment: Including *r_HDRBloomRatio = 0* in game.cfg?

Comment: @Joachim I tryed to edit all .cfg files with this commands: *r_HDRBrightLevel = 0* and *r_HDRBloomRatio = 0* and *r_Glow = 0* with **read only** flag activated, not work. I also tryed to edit the *Shaders.pak* file to attempt to remove lines related to bloom/glow, but using 7-Zip for do this the game just go to pitch black, the menu appear but the rest its black.

Comment: Thanks for the updates. Can you post an image of what your game looks like currently?

Comment: @Joachim I add an screenshoot on the post (the eccessive glow around the pistol).